# Get all latest action - gives warning `Cannot locate file`

Tags: enterprise-architect

After `get all latest` action in Enterpreise architect i get`warning
saying:

> Cannot locate file 0x800c0006

After pressing `ok` the process continues.

How can i make that warning will not pop out?

Comment: what is the get all latest action?

Comment: @Mart10 `Package control`->`get all latest`
in `EA`
[image](http://imgur.com/a/mN9MZ)

Comment: oh i guess this is a version control thing

Comment: @Mart10 yeah, it is

Answer (score 1):

This problem probably occurs because a file has been removed from the version control system without first "uncontrolling" the corresponding package in EA.
Now EA tries to get the latest version of the file, but the file does't exist anymore.

I guess the only thing you can do is check each and every controlled package to make you you can still do a getlatest. That will allow you to identify the missing file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Except you simply avoid that case by checking that the file is present (in whatever API operation you invoked here).

You should also look into [this wiki](http://www.wiki-errors.com/wiki-errors.php?wiki=0X800C0006) which suggests to run a file system check.